# How to add in-app purchases for Android with Adobe AIR

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe

I'm developing a game in Flash for mobile using Adobe AIR.I want to add in-app purchases for my game,specifically additional style packages that people can buy.I tried to find that information on Android Developers but it only describes the process of managing in-app purchases.
My question is,how do i implement this with Adobe AIR?I've heard of native extensions and stuff but i don't completely understand the product side:
Can players download the packages as spritesheets or can the packages be included in the game from the beginning but activated only when you buy them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android you can do both: Include but deactivate or load it afterwards.

Regarding the requered ANE: Try [this](http://sleepydesign.blogspot.de/2012/07/ane-free-air-native-extensions.html). This is a pretty good list for finding several ANEs

Comment: Thanks!All these are actually included in Adobe Gaming SDK in AIR SDK folder))))

Comment: Yeah,now i know how to implement this,guess i won't have any questions)))

Comment: Cool. Once you game is finished, let us know :)